# Correct way to configure interdependent projects (e.g. tensorflow) in bazel build system so proto imports work as is?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet, tensorflow-serving

As the title suggests, I'm running into an issue where proto import statements do not seem to be relative to the correct path. For concreteness, consider the directory structure in a dir (let's call it ~/base):

```
`>> tree -L 1
├── models
├── my-lib
|     ├── nlp
|        ├── BUILD
|        └── nlp_parser.cc
|     └── WORKSPACE
├── serving
└── tensorflow
```

For those not familiar, `models` (as in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/) has tensorflow (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) as a git submodule, as does `serving`. Because of this coupled with the fact that the git submodules of tensorflow where on different commits and sometimes incompatible, I have removed the gitsubmodule from the projects and symlinked them to the tensorflow repo on the top most directory so that I can manage only one tensor flow repo instead of 3. That is I have done the following:

```
`cd models/syntaxnet; rm -rf tensorflow; ln -s ../../tensorflow/ .; cd -`

`cd serving; rm -rf tensorflow tf_models; ln -s ../tensorflow/ .; ln -s ../models .`
```

Now I want to build a target within `my-lib` that depends on `serving`, `tensorflow`, and `models`. I added these as local repositories in my WORKSPACE as follows (`cat my-lib/WORKSPACE`):

```
workspace(name = "myworkspace")

local_repository(
  name = "org_tensorflow",
  path = __workspace_dir__ + "/../tensorflow",
)

local_repository(
  name = "syntaxnet",
  path = __workspace_dir__ + "/../models/syntaxnet",
)

local_repository(
  name = "tf_serving",
  path = __workspace_dir__ + "/../serving",
)

load('@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace.bzl', 'tf_workspace')
tf_workspace("~/base/tensorflow", "@org_tensorflow")

# ===== gRPC dependencies =====

bind(
    name = "libssl",
    actual = "@boringssl_git//:ssl",
)
bind(
    name = "zlib",
    actual = "@zlib_archive//:zlib",
)
```

Here is my BUILD file (`cat my-lib/nlp/BUILD`):

```
load("@tf_serving//tensorflow_serving:serving.bzl", "serving_proto_library")

cc_binary(
  name = "nlp_parser",
  srcs = [ "nlp_parser.cc" ],
  linkopts = ["-lm"],
  deps = [
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:core_cpu",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:framework",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:lib",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:protos_all_cc",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
        "@syntaxnet//syntaxnet:parser_ops_cc",
        "@syntaxnet//syntaxnet:sentence_proto",
        "@tf_serving//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_config_proto",
        "@tf_serving//tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow:session_bundle_factory",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:signature",
  ],
)
```

Lastly, here is the output of the build (`cd my-lib; bazel build nlp/nlp_parser --verbose_failures`):

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/blah/blah/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/debug/BUILD:33:1: null failed: linux-sandbox failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/blah/blah/execroot/my-lib && \
  exec env - \
  /home/blah/blah/execroot/my-lib/_bin/linux-sandbox @/home/blah/blah/execroot/my-lib/bazel-sandbox/c65fa6b6-9b7d-4710-b19c-4d42a3e6a667-31.params -- bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc '--cpp_out=bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow' '--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bazel-out/host/bin/external/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin' '--grpc_out=bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow' -Iexternal/org_tensorflow -Ibazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow -Iexternal/protobuf/src -Ibazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/protobuf/src external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/debug/debug_service.proto).
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
tensorflow/core/util/event.proto: File not found.
tensorflow/core/debug/debug_service.proto: Import "tensorflow/core/util/event.proto" was not found or had errors.
tensorflow/core/debug/debug_service.proto:38:25: "Event" is not defined.
Target //nlp:nlp_parser failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.776s, Critical Path: 0.42s
```

What is the correct way to add the modules as local_repository in WORKSPACE so that the proto imports work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem after trying to build a project of mine depending on tensorflow on Ubuntu after getting it building on OS X. What ended up working for me was disabling sandboxing with `--spawn_strategy=standalone`